# Segmentation fault when char array is declared inside function

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault

Today I experienced a strange behaviour while writing some C/C++ code and I was wondering what the explanation is.

Here are two code snippets showing the same function, the first one has the static array "char comp[BUFFLEN];" declared outside the function while for the second one it is declared inside the function. BUFFLEN was defined with size 1024.
The odd behaviour I am referring to is this: the first function runs perfectly and provides the expected output while the second one crushes with a segfault. 
I know where the mistake is - I did not allocate memory for k before copying (obviously, after fixing, both variants work well), yet I was hoping someone could tell me what happened and why I did't get an error for the first one. Thanks!

```
char comp[BUFFLEN];
void gen_struct(char* path){
    char pathc[BUFFLEN];
    memset(comp, 0, BUFFLEN);
    comp[0] = '\0';
    strcpy(pathc, path);
    cout << path << endl;
    char* p = strtok(pathc, "/");
    char* k;
    strcpy(k,p);
    do{
        if(p == NULL){
            cout << "Write " << k << " to disk\n";
            break;
        }
        sprintf(comp, "%s/%s", comp, p);
        // strcat(comp, p);
        cout << "Making directory: " << comp << endl;
        // Sysops::mkdir(comp);
        strcpy(k,p);
        p = strtok(NULL, "/");
    }while(true);
}

void gen_struct(char* path){
    char pathc[BUFFLEN];
    char comp[BUFFLEN];
    memset(comp, 0, BUFFLEN);
    comp[0] = '\0';
    strcpy(pathc, path);
    cout << path << endl;
    char* p = strtok(pathc, "/");
    char* k;
    strcpy(k,p);
    do{
        if(p == NULL){
            cout << "Write " << k << " to disk\n";
            break;
        }
        sprintf(comp, "%s/%s", comp, p);
        // strcat(comp, p);
        cout << "Making directory: " << comp << endl;
        // Sysops::mkdir(comp);
        strcpy(k,p);
        p = strtok(NULL, "/");
    }while(true);
}
```

Sorry if the title is inappropriate, I tried to think of something someone would actually google.

Comment: There's no explanation for *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: Your are either using the wrong language, or the wrong objects to represent your data.

Comment: @BlueMoon As a scientist I'd tell you there is an explanation, it's just not always the same! The behavior is undefined means that it depends on the specific program, platform, running conditions, memory layout, etc. But it doesn't mean that there is no explanation, it means that there is no way to predict what is going to happen, hence it's undefined.

Comment: Undefined behaviour is undefined behaviour. Anything can happening, including the program not crashing.

Comment: @iharob `The behavior is undefined means that it depends on the specific program, platform, running conditions, memory layout, etc.` really? What UB means there's no sane explanation for the behaviour. Even if you know all that you list, the program could have differently *even under the same conditions* on a different run. Don't spread misinformation.

Comment: `The odd behaviour I am referring to` The behavior is *not* odd.  When you write C++ code that produces undefined behavior, anything can happen.  Maybe it is "odd behaviour" if you have written programs in other languages, where the running of a buggy program is always deterministic.  Not so with C++.

Comment: @BlueMoon I already had a similar discussion about **Chaos Theory** once, with someone studying it and claiming that Chaotic Systems where **non deterministic**, they failed to understand that determinism and non-linearity had nothing to do with each other, and that Chaos was caused by non-linearity of deterministic systems, it's very similar in this case, and I will **not** have this discussion again, because I am sure that you will never accept what I say and you will try to prove me wrong no matter what.

Comment: @BlueMoon I am sorry if you think I am spreading misinformation, there is a lot of **misinformation** on the internet, maybe that's why you don't understand what undefined behavior means, if you had enough information you can predict how a program which intentionally invokes undefined behavior will behave, that's why some bugs in software are exploited by attackers, like for example, buffer overflows.

Comment: @BlueMoon there is nothing random in software, even software random number generators are not **really** random, why you think it's important to call `srand(someSeed)`? That is a weakness of security systems too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just looking at your code without inspecting in detail shows an evident problem

1. You don't check if `strtok()` returned `NULL`, dereferencing a `NULL` pointer is **undefined behavior**, the faulty line is

   ```
   char* p = strtok(pathc, "/");
   ```

   and you `strcpy()` the "*token*" right after that.
2. You don't allocate space for `k`, so `k` is not initialized and it contains garbage, trying to write to the "*address*" it points to, is **undefined behavior**.

The issue will probably occur as soon as this line

```
strcpy(k, p)
```

is reached, it's not possible to predict what the behavior of the program will be, but you can expect it to behave differently when variables are declared/defined at different places, since the program layout will be different and the behavior generally depends on that.

You are also working as if it was a c program, while it's evidently a c++ program, c++ programmers wouldn't work with strings using `strtok()` and `char` pointers, c programmers have little to do about it and must work with this things, since you are using a c++ compiler I would suggest `std::string` and you can split the string, don't need to worry about allocating memory, etc.

Comment: I am not used to thinking about undefined behaviour although I knew it existed. I will consider this in the future. Thank you!